# xaringan: add custom Latex file with macros

Tags: r, r-markdown, mathjax, xaringan

Is it possible to import a Latex macro file, for instance

```
\newcommand{\Xcal}{\mathcal{X}
```

so that I can then use it between `$...$` as `$\Xcal$`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this seems to work:

```
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: {
    Macros: {
      Xcal: "{\\mathcal{X}}",
      water: "{H_2O}"
    }
  }
});
</script>

$\water$    
$\Xcal$
```

[image]

It is important to use `type=text/x-mathjax-config` on the script tag, so mathjax finds the block. Details on defining macros in 
MathJax can be found [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html?highlight=Macro#defining-tex-macros).

An alternative is to include the definition using the `before_body` YAML option:

```
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
    includes:
      before_body: local.html
---
```

Comment: Thank you. It does work indeed! I kind of wish you could use existing Latex macros from a file, but I guess I can always write a quick program to parse them into this format

Answer (score 5):

MathJax allows you to define macros. In Xaringan, you simply put your macros in double dollar signs.

````
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "⚔<br/>with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "2016/12/12 (updated: `r Sys.Date()`)"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

$$\newcommand{\Xcal}{\mathcal{X}}$$

# Math Macros

You can define your own macros by putting them in double dollars signs.

```
$$\newcommand{\Xcal}{\mathcal{X}}$$
```

This symbol $\Xcal$ is a calligraphic X.
````